# Sort dictionary into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to order a dictionary that has a dictionaries inside:

```
{
 1: {
'Schedule_info': {
  'Lunes': '',
  'Martes': 'mañana',
  'Miercoles': '',
  'Jueves': 'mañana',
  'Viernes': '',
  'Sabado': '',
  'Domingo': ''
},
'Hours_Worked': 14,
'mandatory': False
},
2: {
'Schedule_info': {
  'Lunes': '',
  'Martes': '',
  'Miercoles': '',
  'Jueves': '',
  'Viernes': '',
  'Sabado': '',
  'Domingo': ''
},
'Hours_Worked': 0,
'mandatory': False
 },
 3: {
'Schedule_info': {
  'Lunes': '',
  'Martes': 'Tarde',
  'Miercoles': '',
  'Jueves': 'Tarde',
  'Viernes': '',
  'Sabado': '',
  'Domingo': ''
},
'Hours_Worked': 12,
'mandatory': False
}
}
```

I'm trying to apply this code:

```
sort_df = sorted(df.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

but this code is only when th dictionary structure is somthing like:

```
orders = {
'cappuccino': 54,
'latte': 56,
'espresso': 72,
'americano': 48,
'cortado': 41
}
```

I want to have the dictionary ordered because I want to select the dictionary with the "Hours_Worked" property higher or lower.

The other way that I thinking is to do a for-loop but I think that this way is a very inefficient way.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sorting by just the inner dict, you need to sort by the hours key of the inner dicts if you want to sort by that:

```
sort_df = dict(sorted(df.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Hours_Worked']))
```

Results:

```
{2: {'Schedule_info': {'Lunes': '', 'Martes': '', 'Miercoles': '', 'Jueves': '', 'Viernes': '', 'Sabado': '', 'Domingo': ''},
     'Hours_Worked': 0, 
     'mandatory': False}, 
 3: {'Schedule_info': {'Lunes': '', 'Martes': 'Tarde', 'Miercoles': '', 'Jueves': 'Tarde', 'Viernes': '', 'Sabado': '', 'Domingo': ''}, 
     'Hours_Worked': 12, 
     'mandatory': False}, 
 1: {'Schedule_info': {'Lunes': '', 'Martes': 'mañana', 'Miercoles': '', 'Jueves': 'mañana', 'Viernes': '', 'Sabado': '', 'Domingo': ''}, 
     'Hours_Worked': 14, 
     'mandatory': False}}
```